# How to fetch DuckDuckGo API

Tags: javascript, get, fetch-api, fetchrequest, duckduckgo-api

i made a single webpage to get [DuckDuckGo Instant Answer API](https://api.duckduckgo.com/api) result,
https://adamorielly.github.io/Ducksearch/

But i'm getting 405 Method Not Allowed response when i just tried to make a fetch GET request, Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows.

I guess the purpose of this API is to allow other apps to get search results and render them on their apps,
am i doing it wrong? , here's my code:

```
<section class="bd-container">
    <div class="duck__search">
        <div class="form__div">
            <input type="text" id="input1" class="form__input" placeholder="enter your search query">
            <label for="" class="form__label"></label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="button" id="form__button" value="Search">
        <div class="duck__result" id="duck__result"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

my javascript:

```
const searchBtn = document.getElementById('form__button')
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let formInputs = document.getElementById('input1').value
    fetch('https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q='+formInputs+'&format=json', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.status)
        console.log(res.statusText)
        let result = JSON.parse(res.body)
    }).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.error('err'))
})
```

if the API doesn't allow fetch request, is there another way to do it

Comment: If you remove the headers it should work. There is no Content-type in a GET request as you aren't sending any content. You are probably confusing the request content type with the response type

Comment: @charlietfl thanks mate, i removed it, status 200 ok, and i got error after i don't know how to get the json response or the data to make it into HTML :)),

Comment: Oh.  You aren't returning the `res.json()` promise `fetch(url).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>console.log(data))`

Comment: @charlietfl with res.json() i got  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=DuckDuckGo&format=json.